# Linear operator as antisymmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $A\colon P_2 \to P_2$ be a linear operator (where $P_2$ is a vector space of polynomials such that $\deg(P)\le 2$) defined as

$$A(e,e)=\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 2 & a \\ 1 & 2 & c \\ b & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

where $e=\{1,t,t^2\}.$

$a)$ Determine $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that the matrix of the operator $A$ in the basis $\left\{ 1+t,t-t^2,1+t+t^2 \right\}$ is a symmetrical matrix.

$b)$ Is there a basis $e'$ such that $A$ is an anti-symmetrical matrix?

I've managed to do the $a)$ part but I'm not even sure where to begin with part $b)$. How would one approach this? Thank you in advance!!

Comment: What is the answer to (a)? If the resulting matrix has full rank, then the answer to (b) is almost immediate: If a matrix $B$ is skew, then nonzero eigenvalues (including multiplicity) come in pairs $\pm \lambda$. So, if $B$ has odd size, then it must have at least one zero eigenvalue and hence it does not have full rank.

Comment: How would you approach this if you didn't have the a) part a priori? And also,  why is that statement about eigenvalues coming in pairs true?

Comment: I asked about (a) because part (b) is asking about a specific matrix. A matrix has the same eigenvalues as its transpose, including multiplicity, so if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of a skew matrix $B$, it is also an eigenvalue of $B^T = -B$, and so $-\lambda$ is also an eigenvalue of $B$. In fact, if $B$ is real, then the eigenvalues are all imaginary. So, a necessary condition for a linear map $\Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$ to be skew in some basis is for its eigenvalues to be $-i \mu, 0, i \mu$ for some real number $\mu$, and one can show that this is also sufficient.

Comment: Since the answer for (a) is necessary for (b), perhaps include it in your problem statement, and give the resulting matrix $A$?

Comment: b) part isn't directly related to the a) part, it's asking about the operator A...

Comment: But the operator depends on $a, b, c$, and these values are fixed by part (a).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second part asks you whether the matrix representing $A$ (which I'll also denote by $A$) can be similar to an antisymmetric matrix $B$. An antisymmetric matrix must have zero trace because

$$ \operatorname{tr}(B) = -\operatorname{tr}(-B^T) = -\operatorname{tr}(B^T) = -\operatorname{tr}(B) \implies \operatorname{tr}(B) = 0. $$

Since $\operatorname{tr}(A) = 2$ and trace is invariant under similarity, there is no basis in which the operator $A$ is represented by an antisymmetric matrix.